# How to make a navbar position:absolute; with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

This is my navbar html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">EsportGRID</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <?php if(Request::path() == "/") { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="/">Start</a></li> 
                    <li <?php if(Request::path() == "about") { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div class="divider"></div>
                    <?php if(Auth::check()) { ?>
                    <li><a href="#">{{ ucfirst(Auth::user()->username); }}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ URL::route('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <li  <?php if(Request::path() == "login") { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                    <li <?php if(Request::path() == "registration") {echo 'class="active"'; } ?>> <a href="/registration">Registration</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

This is my CSS:

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.navbar .navbar-default{
    position:absolute !important;
}

*{
    border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

I cannot for the life of me make the navbar position absolute, make it follow with the scroll. Would appreciate some help. I've tried using !important and not using !important, but I think the problem mainly resides with containers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want `navbar-fixed-top`

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```